# Почему при написании кода на C# возникает куча ошибок?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу сделать игру раннер.

Но когда пишу код для того чтобы мой персонаж двигался по дороге бесконечно в Юнити вылезает куча ошибок.

```
Assets\Scripts\RoadSpawner.cs(15,27): error CS1061: 'List<GameObject>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no accessible extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'List<GameObject>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\Scripts\RoadSpawner.cs(21,31): error CS0119: 'RoadSpawner' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Assets\Scripts\RoadSpawner.cs(22,21): error CS0117: 'RoadSpawner' does not contain a definition for 'Remove'

Assets\Scripts\RoadSpawner.cs(22,28): error CS0103: The name 'movedRoad' does not exist in the current context

Assets\Scripts\RoadSpawner.cs(23,53): error CS0117: 'RoadSpawner' does not contain a definition for 'Count'

Assets\Scripts\RoadSpawner.cs(23,22): error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'
```

Код TestCharController:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestCharController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float movementSpeed = 10f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float hMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementSpeed / 2;
        float vMovement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * movementSpeed;

        transform.Translate(new Vector3(hMovement, 0, vMovement) * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Код TestCameraController:

```
   using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestCameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform player;

    private float yOffset = 1.5f;
    private float xOffset = -4f;
    private float zOffset = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(player.position.x + xOffset, player.position.y + yOffset, player.position.z + zOffset);
    }
}
```

Код RoadSpawner:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RoadSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> roads;
    private float offset = 60f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if(roads != null && roads.Count > 0)
        {
            roads = roads.OrderBy(roads => r.transform.position.z).ToList();
        }
    }

    public void MoveRoad()
    {
        GameObject moveRoad = RoadSpawner[0];
        RoadSpawner.Remove(movedRoad);
        float newZ = RoadSpawner.Equals[RoadSpawner.Count - 1].transform.position.z + offset;
        moveRoad.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, newZ);
    roads.Add(moveRoad);
}
}
```

Код SpawnManager:

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста, я новичёк в создании игр и просто не понимаю что мне делать.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz6pa.jpg

Comment: Во-первых, код лучше кидать через какой-нибудь сервис вроде pastebin или прямо в stackoverflow. Во-вторых, ошибки судя по их описанию связаны с не знанием языка. Потому настоятельно рекомендую перед тем как начать что-либо делать, хотя бы разобраться в особенностях языка. Начните с написания простых функциональных программ на C#, а затем плавно переходите в ООП.

Comment: Ошибки связаны с тем, что нарушен синтаксис языка. Такое ощущение, что вы пишите ваш код на каком-то другом языке, не C#. К тому же в Stack Overflow есть прекрасная возможность выкладывать код (КОД, а не картинка) с помощью тройных обратных кавычек: ``` (или одинарных)

Comment: Вам надо выучить хотя бы основы C#, без этого, думаю, продолжать писать хоть игру-раннер, хоть что-то еще, абсолютно бесполезно. Вы ведь вряд ли станете делать ремонт в квартире, если в первый раз видите молоток? Вот и здесь то же самое. Посмотрите какие-либо онлайн-курсы по самому языку без его приложения к Unity, изучите синтаксис, разберитесь в языковых конструкциях, это займет максимум неделю. После этого возвращайтесь к Unity и своему проекту.

Comment: Только представьте себе, что для того, чтобы мне воспроизвести вашу проблему у себя, мне надо перепечатывать ваш код с картинок. Я конечно же не буду этого делать.

Answer (score 1):

Подключите Linq в RoadSpawner в самом начале.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Это что касается первой ошибки.

А остальные ошибки из-за непонимания основ.

`RoadSpawner[0]` не имеет смысла. Подозреваю, что вместо:

```
GameObject moveRoad = RoadSpawner[0];
```

Должно быть:

```
GameObject moveRoad = roads[0];
```